# How to call function within itself in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Let say I have this using nodejs and i want to call function2 from function1.
Is it possible to do this?

```
module.exports = {

 function1 : {function2()},

 function2: {}

}
```

Comment: you can return function 2 and then use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do somthing like this:

```
var obj = {}

obj.function1 = function(){
    obj.function2();
}

obj.function2 = function(){}

module.exports = obj;
```

Or, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    function1: function(){this.function2();}, /*This should not be an arrow function
                                                because it dose not define its own 
                                                keyword this*/

    function2: function(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Note that `function1` must be a `function(){}` instead of `()=>{}` so that it can access `this`.

```
module.exports = {
    function1: function(){this.function2();},
    function2: ()=>{console.log("function2");}
}
```